# Hardware for debugging and testing of Android TV Application

Tags: android-tv

I am going to build application for Android TV. For debugging and testing I need a hardware device of TV. I have no idea about hardware of Android TV device.Which device is suitable for debugging and testing for Android TV application?

Comment: Any device will do. ADB is available on all Android devices, including TV, and thats all you could need for testing ad debugging.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @ULazdins's answer, you can check this [article](http://www.mikevandrongelen.info/2015/12/apps-on-big-screen-iii-debugging-android-tv.html) about *Debugging on an Android TV*. Before you begin building apps for TV, you must know first the [prerequisites](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html):

- [Update your SDK tools to version 24.0.0 or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#GetTools)
  The updated SDK tools enable you to build and test apps for TV.
- [Update your SDK with Android 5.0 (API 21) or higher](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html#GetTools)
  The updated platform version provides new APIs for TV apps.
- [Create or update your app project](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/create-project.html)
  In order to access new APIs for TV devices, you must create a project or modify an existing project that targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can u give me idea about android tv box? Which Android box is supported android TV and used for testing and debugging app? Below are the link of two android TV boxes https://www.asus.com/us/Home-Entertainment/Nexus_Player, http://www.mi.com/en/mibox. Can it is supported debugging and testing for android TV?